# c# interop excel - How to get coordinates value specifing a cell value

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Is there a way to get the coordinates of a cell giving a cell value?

For example I want to find the cell coordinates where there is the word: "General_Assembly".

Can you give me some help about this issue?

Comment: Could Range.Find help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find.aspx

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look it up on [google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=c%23+excel+interop+search+cell)? Do you have any code that you are working on?

Comment: @EricS ok it works with Range.Find. Very good. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know dimensions of your table, you can make two simple loops (for row and column) and check text of each cell.

```
Excel.Worksheet ws = *load your excel sheet from excel file*;
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
int maxRows = *whatever is the height of your table*
int maxColumns = *whatever is the width of your table*
string searchFor = "General_Assembly";

for(int i = 1; i <= maxRows; i++)
    for(int j = 1; j <= maxColumns; j++)
        if((ws.Cells[i, j] as Range).Value.ToString() == searchFor)
        {
            row = i;
            column = j;
        }
```

And that's how you get row and column index, and also learn how to loop trough matrix/table cells.

You don't realy need to know the dimensions, but maximum row count in any excel file is 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns, and that would take too much time.

Also, as suggested as @Xiaoy312, you asked without giving any effort of finding what you need yourself. I didn't, but you try google-ing "C# Excel interop how to find cell by cell value". I litelarly made that up just now, but that is the real "help" that you asked for. I provided the code so you can understand how to loop trough table/matrix. Again, you can learn this loop by google-ing "c# how to find cell value in table/matrix". So, for your next question, please refer to any tutorials and/or online help for what you are in searh of.